# Combining independent probabilities: ghosts in a haunted house

Tags: probability, statistics

Despite taking several statistics courses in college years ago, I've never had a mind for probabilities, so please excuse what may be a very basic question.

To make this fun, let's say you are in a haunted house and I am giving probabilities on encountering ghosts, room by room.  Here are the probabilities:

- 1/12 chance of encountering exactly 1 ghost in the dining room
- 1/16 chance of encountering exactly 2 ghosts in the kitchen
- 1/4 chance of encountering exactly 1 ghost in the bedroom
- 1/30 chance of encountering either exactly 2 ghosts or exactly 8 ghosts in the cellar
- 1/36 chance of encountering either exactly 3 ghosts or exactly 18 ghosts in the library

*Probabilities are all or nothing.* In the dining room, for example, there is an 11/12 probability of encountering zero ghosts.

These probabilities are independent of each other (e.g., encountering a ghost in one room does not affect whether or not you will encounter a ghost in another room).

Here are my questions (assume you enter every room):

1. **What is the probability you will encounter *at least one* ghost?**
2. **Including upper and lower bounds, how many ghosts can you expect to encounter, if any?**

Abstractions are helpful, but please also solve the problem with the concrete values above so I have an easier time mapping your work to an abstracted solution.  Thank you!

Comment: Is the chance of encountering exactly $1$ ghost in the kitchen equal to $0$? Is the chance of encountering $2$ ghosts in the cellar the same as that of encountering $3$? Is that chance in both cases $1 \over 30$ or $1 \over {7 \cdot 30}$ (so that the chance of encountering any ghosts sums up to $1 \over 30$)?

Comment: In the kitchen you have a 1/16 chance of encountering exactly 2 ghosts and a 15/16 chance of encountering 0 ghosts. As for the ranges of ghosts, I'm really only looking for a calculation that includes 2 ghosts in the cellar and 3 ghosts in the library and another that includes 8 ghosts in the cellar and 18 ghosts in the library (the upper and lower bounds I was referring to).

Comment: I've updated the question to be more exacting with my language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{align} P(\text{at least one ghost}) &= 1 - P(\text{no ghosts}) \\&= 1 - P(\text{no ghost in dining room}) \cdot P(\text{no ghost in kitchen}) \cdots  \\&= 1 - \Big (1-\frac{1}{12} \Big ) \Big (1-\frac{1}{16} \Big ) \Big(1-\frac{1}{4}\Big)\cdots\end{align}$$

$$\begin{align} N_\text{expected} &= N_\text{dining room} \cdot P(\text{dining room}) + N_\text{kitchen} \cdot P(\text{kitchen}) + \dots \\&= 1\cdot \frac{1}{12} + 2 \cdot \frac{1}{16} + 1 \cdot \frac{1}{4} + \dots \end{align}$$

Comment: Excellent.  I had the right answer to N{expected}, but P(at least one ghost) was eluding me.  Thanks for your help!